# Web Service Software Factory install with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, wssf

I have a number of WCF services implemented using Web Service Software Factory from http://servicefactory.codeplex.com

All these services were implemented using Visual Studio 2010. Has anyone used Web Service Software Factory with Visual Studio 2012? On the website I see a zip file which has just the source code. I am not sure by the documentation given on the website if there in an install available for visual studio 2012. If it is, how can I install it? Where are the install files available and what order to install them?

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same situation and here are the steps that solved my problem.

1. Download the source of the extension, compatible with VS 2012 (zip
   is available on codeplex site)
2. Install SDK of VS 2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff718165.aspx)
3. Install SDK of Visualization and Modeling (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30680)
4. Reload the solution
5. Reload any of the unloaded projects in solution (right click the unload project and reload)
6. Finally build the solution and get required VSIX installer from the bin folder of project named “Service Factory Package”
   Happy coding

Comment: I just noticed that there is also a Guidance Automation Toolkit and Guidance Automation Extensions for VS2012. Those are also required for the WSSF.

Comment: This all looks good, but how do I actually create a service using this now?  I no longer see "Web Service Software Factory" under the Guidance Packages section of the templates list.

Comment: Guidance Automation Toolkit and Guidance Automation Extensions are not required for latest WSSF in VS 2012. It uses DSL and standard project files. To use, create new project and add Web Service Software Factory 2010 Model from Add Item dialog. Then add WCF project templates via Add Project dialog.